# Set custom window position on wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I think there is a bug with the Window.Width and Window.Height of wpf. I need my window to cover my entire desktop (there are two monitors) but first let me show you why I think there is a bug.

### First let me show you the resolution of my monitors: (both have the same resolution)

[image]

### this is the window on visual studio that I am working with

[image]

I don't know if you guys know AutoIt but it is a nice program to automate simple stuff. so if I want to resize my MainWindow to cover all the space in my first monitor (same thing as if I where maximizing a window) I will execute this method on autoit:
[image]

and when I execute that code my window that I am creating in visual studio extends and it appears exactly as if it where to be maximized.

[image]

so far the coordinates seem to be working.

now when I do the same thing with c# on wpf:

---

```
    public static void setWindowSize(System.Windows.Window w)
    {
        w.Left = 0;
        w.Top =0;
        w.Width = 1920;
        w.Height = 1079;
    }
```

The parameter w will be the MainWindow. When I execute that take a look how the window get's resized:
[image]

I placed the older image next to it so that you guys can compare it. Why are the dimensions not the same? I belive that the Window.Width and Window.Height properties do not work correctly. or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What DPI is your primary monitor? The default scale for "Width" is in 1/96", which is pixels on most displays. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx

Comment: I have also tried using the ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties instead and I get the same problem.

Comment: Your monitor is definitely 96 DPI? Setting the width works fine for me. If your monitor is something other than 96 DPI then I can see how it might behave the way you're seeeing.

Comment: What do you mean by DPI? and if that is the problem what I have to do in my code in oder to fix it? Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Dots Per Inch. The number of pixels your monitor physically squeezes into an inch. See this link: http://ideareboot.com/blogs/index.php/2008/05/21/pixel-dilemma-and-wpf/

Comment: thanks that explains my problem. The reason why I want to fix this with code is because I don't want to modify my users dpi in their resolution. I guess I will have to compile an AutoiIt application and embed it with my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to cover your main monitor then

`Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`

if you want to cover both monitors

`Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight`

Answer (score 1):

try out this

Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth,
  Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight,

Comment: thanks that did not overflowed. I actually need the window to cover all the monitors. when executing that it only covered my main monitor.